# change rvm ruby version with ansible playbook

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm, ansible, rvmrc

I have ansible-playbook succesfully installing rvm. But now i must change default ruby version. I have tried with:

```
- name: Install Bundler
  command: bash -lc "rvm use 2.1.2-p95"
```

or

```
- name: use 2.1
  shell: /usr/bin/env bash -lc "rvm use 2.1.2-p95"
```

or

```
- name: use 2.1
  shell: rvm use 2.1.2-p95
```

But nothing ansible looks like all works fine but when i log ssh with the same user wich use ansible and run `rvm current` the ruby version is the same.

I suspect from ssh and bash login shell but I can see solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

```
- name: Install Bundler
  command: rvm alias create default ruby-2.1.2-p95
```

btw. have you seen RVMs support for Ansible: https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-ansible

Comment: works great! Can you explain why your solution works?

Comment: it works because ansible is different session, when you log in RVm will try to find default ruby and load it, if it was not defined - then you get nothing